# Submit only specific tests to Xamarin Test Cloud

Tags: xamarin-test-cloud

We have an Android and iOS applications and we wrote some Xamarin Test Cloud tests in Calabash. We can run them successfully both locally and on the cloud. Taken from the [docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/calabash/working-with/submitting-tests-to-xamarin-test-cloud/#Submitting_Calabash_Tests) on the Xamarin website, we have a few parameters available when we submit to the cloud, but none of them provides a possibility to run only specific tests (features). Our tests are put in source control, so at the moment, the only resolution we could find is to temporary delete the ones we do not want to submit and run the `test-cloud` command.

**My question:**

Is there a way to only submit a specific `*.feature` file? Or run only tests based on a tag (e.g. `@somefeature`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but not with a feature file. The best way to do this is by [Categorizing your tests](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/working-with/nunit-categories/). Then you can use the `--category` [parameter](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/working-with/nunit-categories/#Submitting_Tests_to_Test_Cloud_by_Category) in your Xamarin Test Cloud command line submission.